# pug seems to break bootstrap styling[resolved]

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, pug

I'm trying to render a page with pug that displays either a welcome message or login/signup links. The message/links reside within a bootstrap navbar. My code is like the following:

```
             .script 
                    if user 
                        document.getElementById('portal').innerHTML 
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/account">Welcome! #{user.username}</a>
                            </li>
                    else 
                        document.getElementById('portal').innerHTML
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Signup</a>
                            </li>
```

which causes the navbar's styling to break. The nav-items are originally supposed to be side by side.

Resolved, I wasn't paying attention to the finalized html structure, turns out a nested class is stopping the style from cascading as expected.

Comment: pug is not breaking you html.. see if and else statements working properly something is breaking in your html structure and/or in your css.

Comment: The only thing that I changed is adding the if else statement, which seems to be working properly except for the weird styling side effect.